# Java variables name and reserved words

Tags: java

"lenght" is a predefined variable in java. But Java users can use "lenght" is a variable name in our own classes.

Example:
int length = 10;

1. Why length is not a reserved word in java?
2. Is it ok to use length as a variable name in a class?.

Comment: `length` is a property of a class and it doesn't have to belong to all classes. It's fine to use `length` as variable name in a class

Answer (score 1):

Length is an instance variable for arrays, so as long as you don't use in the context of someArray.length, it is not reserved. The string class has an instance method called length, but again, not reserved.